# Javascript - Import HTML from external file

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple webpage (actually implemented as an iFrame in a MS Business Central (BC) page) which is displaying some address fields for input. This is implemented into the BC page using...

```
HTMLContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
  '<div class="addyaddin">' +
  '  <div class="control">' +
  '    <div class="caption">Address</div>' +
  '    <div class="value">' +
  '      <input type="text" class="addressline" id="address1" placeholder="Start typing an address.." auto-complete/>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '  </div>' +

  '  <div class="control">' +
  '    <div class="caption">City</div>' +
  '    <div class="value">' +
  '      <input type="text" id="city" auto-complete/>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '  </div>' +

  '  <div class="control">' +
  '    <div class="caption">Region</div>' +
  '    <div class="value">' +
  '      <input type="text" id="region" auto-complete/>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '</div>');
```

Which works fine, however the html is multiline so it all gets a bit messy. What I'd like to have is an html file which I could simply read into a variable and then have that display. This means my code is a lot tidier and I can mess around with the html without having to string a whole lot of lines of html together in the insertAdjacementHTML statement.

Something like...

```
ReadHtmlFile('\myfile.html',textVariable);
HTMLContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',textVariable);
```

Unfortunately JavaScript is something I'm not really familiar with so it's been a bit hit and miss up to this point. Hoping someone can guide me in the right direction

Cheers
Craig

Comment: You need [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you asked for, but:

I just copied, cleaned extra spaces and changed the variables names of an answer by [@Majid Laiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438628/majid-laissi) in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file), just to test it. The `function` works well. A new *index.txt* file with the following content is created and saved in my computer:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Just a paragraph</p>
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
</ul>
```

When the request succeed (*file* has been recognized), the content (HTML Elements) will be stored in the `variable` *text*, and printed to the `console`. Check:

```
var text = new_file.responseText;
console.log(text);
```

This way you can manipulate the content easily.

You may have to update the path, depends on your folder structure:

```
read_file("index.txt"); /* The path to the file */
```

**Credit:**
[@Majid Laiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438628/majid-laissi) - [How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

**The Code:**

```js
function read_file(file){
    var new_file = new XMLHttpRequest();
    new_file.open("GET", file, false);
    new_file.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(new_file.readyState === 4){
            if(new_file.status === 200 || new_file.status == 0){
                var text = new_file.responseText;
                console.log(text);
            }
        }
    }
    new_file.send(null);
}

read_file("index.txt"); /* The path to the file */
```